# Custom order in view results

Tags: views, 8

```
function mymodule_views_pre_render(Drupal\views\ViewExecutable $view) {
    if ($view->current_display == 'current_display' && $view->id() == 'view_id') {
            $sort = array(21, 20, 22, 23, 25, 24, 19, 18);
            $new_sort = array();
            foreach ($view->result as $key => $result) {
                 $new_sort[array_search($result->tid, $sort)] = $result;
            }
            ksort($new_sort);  
            $count = 0;
            foreach ($new_sort as $key => $result) {
                $view->result[$count] = $result;
                $count += 1;
            }
        }
}
```

I've got a view which render some results I need to reorder. I don't want to use Weight, cause it's still used somewhere else.

`$sort` is the new order I need. 

So for each results, I check his `tid`, match him with the key in the `sort` and push him in a new array. For example, for `$result->tid = 22` :

```
$new_sort[array_search(22, $sort)] = $result;
```

returns

```
$new_sort[2] = $result;
```

The code above is correct as my var_dump is. But results are still displayed in the default order. Did I miss something to make my new order efficient ?